# how to write a join query with in this situation: 1 if not exist, not restriction 2 if exist, it must be in these time

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

At the beginning I need to handle a simple situation as entry control:

table A:

id | name | date

11 | name | 2017-01-01

12 | name | 2017-01-01

13 | name | 2017-01-01

23 | name | 2017-01-01

table B:

id | begin_date | end_date

11 | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-31

12 | 2017-02-01 | 2017-02-15

13 | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-31

==========================================

I should find the people who can get in between the begin_date and end_date:

My initial query is:

```
select a.id from tmp.a join tmp.b on a.id=b.id and (a.date between b.begin_date and b.end_date);
```

and it should return id 11 and 13, which is correct.

But then my boss tell me that id 23 should also get in as it is not in table B so there is no restriction in begin_date and end_date.

Is there any way I can modify my query so that the query can also return id 23?

A general question will be how to 'join' in a situation that: when the record exists, perform inner join with certain conditions, when it does not exist, perform as left join.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please do following changes :

select id from A left join B on ((A.id=B.id and (A.entry_date between B.begin_date and end_date)) or B.begin_date IS NULL)

1. Use the left join
2. And one more or condition i.e. B.begin_date IS NULL

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two operations here, one you have already done and other one with union you can combine other required result to first one.

```
select id from A join B on A.id=B.id and (A.entry_date between B.begin_date and end_date)
Union
Select id from A where A.id not in
(Select id from B)
```